# Using global parameters in nested models of ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, parameters

I have a model that consists of two nested models and various parameters. There are two parameters that are common to all of the models (including the overall “grand” model). The common parameters are in-line variables and serve to assign unique file names to the models’ output.

Is there a way to set the values of these parameters at a single time and then have these values propagate through the nested models?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - I think the way to figure out how to do it is by setting up very simple master and sub models.

The master model should do no more than take in a string from its tool dialog and then run the sub-model.

The sub-model should take as one of its inputs a string and use that string to perhaps create a shapefile using the string as its name.  You should be able to run this model either standalone (get it working that way first) or as a sub-model.

You then just need to connect the string variable from the master model to the string input of the sub-model.

No doubt your actual models will be much more complex than this but if you can get the simple test models working then it will be much easier to picture how you can do the same for more complex examples as you encounter them.